# JQuery Datable throwing error for valid "columns" option parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, frontend

Ok so i have a jquery datatable which is structured like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#tableContent').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "path/to/api",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            }],
            "columns": [
                null,
                { "data": "data1", "name": "data1", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "data2", "name": "data2", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "data3", "name": "data3", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "data4", "name": "data4", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "data5", "name": "data5", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "data6", "name": "data6", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "data7", "name": "data7", "autoWidth": true }
            ],
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        });

        table.on('order.dt search.dt page.dt', function () {
            table.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
            });
        }).draw();
});
```

```html
<table class="tableWrapper" id="tableContent">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>data1</th>
                <th>data2</th>
                <th>data3</th>
                <th>data4</th>
                <th>data5</th>
                <th>data6</th>
                <th>data7</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Here is the JSON response to the Api being called

```
{   
    "draw":"1",
    "recordsFiltered":48,
    "recordsTotal":48,
    "data":[
        {
            "data1":"XXXX",
            "data2":"XXXX",
            "data3":"XXXX",
            "data4":"XXXX",
            "data5":"XXXX",
            "data6":"XXXX",
            "data7":"XXXX"
        }...
    ]
}
```

It throws this error :

"DataTables warning: table id=tableContent - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22) [(Attached error message picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aCSO.png)

BUT! shortly after the error is thrown, the data loads in with no issues.

Replacing `null` with `{data:null}` seems to get rid of the error but it messes with my index column. What was supposed to be a sequence of 1,2,3,4... is now just a bunch of [object Object]
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvwke.png)

Comment: The code in your question has syntax errors - it looks like incomplete copy/paste problems. Can you [edit] to fix? Also, can you provide a sample of the raw JSON text response?

Comment: @andrewjames I fixed it, and also provided the sample JSON response

Comment: As you realize, with your comments about replacing `null` with `{data:null}`, your HTML table specifies 8 columns. Your ajax response only provides data for 7 of them. That `<th>#</th>` column is left with no data - which is not valid for DataTables. How are you intending to populate that index column? Where is the data (1, 2, 3...) coming from?

Comment: @andrewjames, the indexing column is populated by the ```table.on('order.dt search.dt page.dt')```. I thought I could just pass in a null value and then have it replaced once the dataTables's events are triggered.

Comment: @andrewjames, but yeah thanks for the help! I should just resort to dealing with the indexing on the server side instead of client side

Comment: OK - thank you for the clarification - now I understand (it was actually quite clear in your question). I can show you a client-side approach, in a couple of minutes, in case you are still interested.

Comment: @andrewjames, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to get what you want. Here is one way, which uses the internal DataTables index assigned to each row. This assignment is purely sequential: the first row added to the table (from the first data object in your JSON) is index 0 - and so on:

```
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return meta.row + 1;
    }
  } ]
```

You already have a `targets: 0` in your sample, so adding in this should be straightforward.

The assigned index will stick to the row, when you sort and filter.

If you want an index which represents where the row is, visually, in the table - that is more complicated (and wouldn't be do-able using server-provided data, of course).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thank you! I really need to improve my jquery docs reading skills

Comment: I forgot to mention, I think with this approach, you will need to move all your column definitions from `"columns"` into `"columnDefs"`, so each one can be given the correct `target`. Try it to be sure. For reference, here is the render function [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).